# Distinguishing file on the filesystem

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I'm trying to distinguish files on the filesystem with the following requirements(assuming all files are within the same filesystem):

1. If file A was renamed to file B it should be appeared to be the same
2. If file A was removed and then created it should appear to be different one

Since I assumed that all files are within the same file system I tended to use `inode_number` for that. But it does not satisfy the point `2.`. Actually:

```
root@spc:~/test# touch test
root@spc:~/test# ls -li
total 0
2098203 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 15 14:55 test
root@spc:~/test# rm test
root@spc:~/test# touch test
root@spc:~/test# ls -li
total 0
2098203 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 15 14:55 test
```

So the two different files appeared to have the same inode number. Is there a way to do this for `linux/ext4`? Maybe we can use some file system specific api to store some meta `uid`?

Comment: The (st_dev, st_ino, st_gen) tuple would suffice, but unfortunately st_gen (inode generation number) is not exported by the kernel. It was considered for the `statx()` call, but it seems it didn't make into it.

Comment: That said, (st_dev, st_ino, st_btime) as provided by [`statx()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html) might work. You'll need to use `syscall()` from `<sys/syscall.h>`, and copy the `struct statx` from kernel [include/linux/uapi/stat.h:struct statx](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/stat.h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set extended filesystem attributes (where supported, i.e. with ext4 when mounted with option `user_xattr`):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <attr/xattr.h>

int main (void) {
    setxattr("test", "user.fileguid", "someuniqueguid", 15, 0);
}
```

and read it back with

```
char uuid[100];
int len = getxattr("test", "user.fileguid", uuid, sizeof(uuid), 0);
```

If this attribute should only be modified by a privileged process, you can use the `security` namespace instead of `user` (i.e. attribute-name `security.fileguid`). In this case, the file owner itself cannot modify the attributes himself. If you do not use the `user` namespace, the mount option `user_xattr` isn't even necessary.

However, these attributes are not set immediately after creation of the file. But it should be sufficient to set a random guid at the first time when accessing the file with your tool (i.e. when no guid is set yet).

These file attributes are saved with the inode, so renaming the file or (hard-)linking it will retain the attributes. However, deleting and creating it newly will not.

Answer (score 1):

Alas it is not possible because:

1. for all data/metadata (including extended attributes, etc) in control of the user, it is possible to set their values/content to the exact same value as the "original" file.
2. for inode number, it is dependent on the filesystem support in the kernel and many of them (FS) recycle inode numbers.

Comment: Can you give some examples of metadata users can set?

Comment: @SomeName timestamps, file length (indirectly), ids, link count, etc